# django - method PUT - Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):

Tags: django, cookies, csrf-protection, django-csrf

My function view for method PUT is:

```
return JsonResponse ({})
```

Using HttpRequester (addon for firefox)

> I get CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

print(request) give following result:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /test/src/4213
```

I don't know what I should do. Could you help me please ?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/src/(\d+)', MyView.as_view(), name='put_'),
]

class MyView(View):
    ....
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request)
            return JsonResponse({})
```

I have no form so I can't include {%csrf_token%}. I have no html file. I try to test it with HttpRequester (firefox addon)

Comment: Are you submitting a form?

Comment: can you please share the urls.py and the views.py to better understand how things are working?

Comment: I edited my first post. Look again and bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that if you are submitting a form you `{%csrf_token%}` as a hidden input in your form.

Also, check to make sure that `CsrfViewMiddleware` is in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py

Comment: I edited my first post. Look again and bottom of this one.

Answer (score 0):

If this view is not for a form but to be accessed directly by something you can remove csrf checks with `csrf_exempt` decorator :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/src/(\d+)', csrf_exempt(MyView.as_view()), name='put_'),
]
```

Comment: The question is not about a form nor ajax, OP is requesting from a firefox extension. So like in any REST API (see DRF for example), csrf can be disabled. But yep, this should have go with more explanations.

Comment: You are right, It is REST API. Should I disable csrf ? How to do it ?

Comment: See the discussion in [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/). You can remove CSRF view per view if this is a mixed environment, BUT only if this REST api view is to be accessed with an authentication schème that is NOT session based. And how to do it, that's it the `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)`

Comment: It doesn't help. There is the same problem still

Comment: By bad, wrong syntax for @method_decorator. Classes based views have to be decorated in urlconf or in dispatch method [DOC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views). Updated answer.